# Why does g++ mark a casting error at not executed code?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

main:

```
#include "multiparse.h"

int main()

{
    parse_string obj;
    obj = "1234";
    //int a = obj;
    //obj = 1234;
    return 0;
}
```

header:

```
class parse_string
{
char* str;
long str_sz;
double val;
bool isnumber;
public:
template<class typename>
    parse_string& operator=(typenamet input)
    {
        //printf("%d == %d\n",typeid(input).name(),typeid(const char*).name());
        if(typeid(input)==typeid(char*)||typeid(input)==typeid(const char*))
        {
            str_sz=strlen(input)+1;
            if(str==0)
            {
                str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            else
            {
                str = (char*)realloc(str,sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            memset(str,0,str_sz);
            strcpy(str,input);
            this->str_to_num();
            isnumber=0;
            printf("A\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("B\n");
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
        }
    }
};
```

g++ error:
multiparse.h error: invalid cast from type 'const char*' to type 'double' at --> 'val = (double)input;'

This code is not executed in my case it will just printf 'A' and not 'B', but g++ doesn't compile this code.
I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your `parse_string` function invokes undefined behavior since it failed to return a `parse_string&`.  Didn't the compiler warn you that you were not returning a value?

Comment: Before someone downvotes this question -- what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?  This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Are you trying to make a data type be two or more different types?  If so, then [Use std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).  If not using C++17, you can use the `boost::variant` or `boost::any` from the boost library.

Comment: The entire code needs to be valid to the compiler, regardless of whether you know it will be executed or not.    The expressions in your `if` statement are evaluated at run time, so the compiler cannot assume the condition is always true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Even though, the code is not executed, it's still part of a `*.cpp` file (as it was `#include`d. So, it becomes apart of a `*.obj`/`*.o` file for this source. 
For this to happen, compiler needs to generate `machine code` for everything in the `*.cpp` file (templates work a bit different, but it's not about them now).

In other words, to get a `.exe`/`.lib`/`.dll` file, which consists of `.obj` files, you need the the files which are to become said `.obj` files to be compiled properly (transcoded to `machine code`).

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, but I don't understand that the error is a cast from 'char*' to 'double', because if 'typeid(input)==typeid(char*)' is true, this cast will never be executed.

Comment: @BeatEngine Compilers do not work this way.  The compiler looks at your source code in total and compiles it.  Unless you're doing something with templates like SFINAE, the code is compiled as-is -- there is no runtime logic being done when the compiler looks at your code.

Comment: @BeatEngine, Yes, like @PaulMcKenzie has already said, compiler doesn't care whether code is executed. If there is code in `*.cpp`, it gets compiled and this is all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my requirements, but I think it's not the best way:

```
parse_string& operator=(char* input)
    {
            str_sz=strlen(input)+1;
            if(str==0)
            {
                str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            else
            {
                str = (char*)realloc(str,sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            memset(str,0,str_sz);
            strcpy(str,input);
            this->str_to_num();
            isnumber=0;
            return *this;
    }

    parse_string& operator=(const char* input)
    {
            str_sz=strlen(input)+1;
            if(str==0)
            {
                str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            else
            {
                str = (char*)realloc(str,sizeof(char)*str_sz);
            }
            memset(str,0,str_sz);
            strcpy(str,input);
            this->str_to_num();
            isnumber=0;
            return *this;
    }

    parse_string& operator=(char input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(int input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(long input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(unsigned char input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(unsigned int input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(unsigned long input)
    {
            val = (double)input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
    parse_string& operator=(double input)
    {
            val = input;
            this->num_to_str();
            isnumber=1;
            return *this;
    }
```

Comment: This code is redundant for no reason.  I suggest you go to the main comment section and post what issue you're trying to solve, instead of giving us your "solution".